# Sharing a redux store between Chrome content script and popup script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, redux

How do I synchronize a Redux store between a Chrome extension's content script and its popup script? They operate in 2 separate environments. I'm aware that there are message passing functions in Chrome to communicate.

I'm wondering how I should integrate this with a Redux store. Or should I just use Chrome's storage to help synchronize the Redux stores?

Comment: I think chrome storage can be a good solution as it can store JSON objects. I don't know Redux so I can't tell if Redux stores are JSON objects. You have to check this condition, but if it is local chrome storage is a good way to share data in between all components of an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reuse anything between different scopes you need to declare it in one and use messaging to/from others.

*manifest.json*

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "description": "Bar",
    "version": "2.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "matches": "<all_urls>"
    }],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

*popup.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="./popup.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

*background.js*

```
var store = createStore(...);
// <...>
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     if (request.action === 'dispatch') {
         store.dispatch(request.arg);
         sendResponse('success');
     }
});
```

*popup.js*

```
var BG = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
var store = BG.store;
// <...>
```

*content.js*

```
var msg = { action: 'dispatch', arg: { type: 'INCREMENT' }};
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function(response) {
    console.log(response) // 'success'
});
```

See the instructional videos for [scope isolation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laLudeUmXHM) and [messaging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4M_a7xejYI).

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this question, and wanted to let future visitors know there is newer package (since this question was asked) that is a basic utility library for building Chrome Extensions with React and Redux...at the highest level, it acts as a 'proxy store' that passes actions and state changes between UI Components and the background page. Could be useful in the OP's scenario. 
https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux/wiki/Introduction

Comment: The package is not being maintained actively anymore. I have tried to get familiar with it and use it in a project. Most important there is no support for Redux-toolkit (at least I can't find any helpful information), which was really annoying.